# Add dynamic radio button object to GridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagridview, telerik

I need to add a custom radio button control that I created based on an if condition to my GridView. My radiobutton will be enabled or disabled based on this condition and will have the text 
changed as well.

I'm trying to figure out how to add a radiobutton object into my data row instead of a string **dt.Columns.Add("FirstName")**.

```
<telerik:RadGrid runat="server" ID="grd1" OnNeedDataSource="grd1_NeedDataSource"> 
<MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<Columns>
     <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Radiobutton header" UniqueName="col1">
      <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:RadioButton ID="rbType" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "rbEnableorDisable")%>' />
       </ItemTemplate>
       </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

       <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="FirstName header" UniqueName="col2">
       <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name")%>' runat="server" />
       </ItemTemplate>
       </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
</Columns>
</MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

CodeBehind

```
Private dt As DataTable
Private dr As DataRow

dt= New DataTable
dt.Columns.Add("rbEnableorDisable")
dt.Columns.Add("FirstName")

Dim rb As RadioButton
rb = New RadioButton

For each item in itemlist //some data iteration declared elsewhere
 dr = dt.NewRow()
   If (Condition)
      rb.Text = "Should be Disabled"
      rb.Enabled = False
   Else
      rb.Text = "Should be Enabled"
      rb.Enabled = True
   End if

   dr.Item("FirstName") = item.FirstName
   dr.Item("rbEnableOrDisable") = rb//?Code for inserting a radio button object
   dt.Rows.Add(dr)
Next

    With grd1
        .DataSource = dt
        .DataBind()
    End With
```

So far with this code
I am only able to display the radiobutton text if i have **dr.Item("rbEnableOrDisable") = rb.Text.**

I need to display the whole radiobutton object(show the text and if it's enabled or disabled among others)

I tried

**LocationData.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("rbType", GetType(RadioButton)))**

but it seems I need to append to the ItemTemplate

Also tried adding the whole column dynamic with:

**grd1.Controls.Add(rb)**

Comment: DanielVorph Thanks for replying. I made changes to the code. I added         dt.Columns.Add("rbType") and had <asp:RadioButton ID="rbType" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "rbEnableorDisable")%>' Enabled='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "rbType")%>' /> This seems to work. Is this acceptable code? or is there another code syntax to pass the value to the dataitem instead of dt.Columns.Add("rbType") which seems to add a column? sorry for the questions i am new to vbnet thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have something in your DataItem to put the radiobutton enabled or disabled and assigment to Enabled property.

Enabled='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "booleanData")%>'

If you need to put RadioButton checked or unchecked use Checked property.

Comment: DanielVorph Thanks for replying. I made changes to the code. I added

Comment: Yes there is another syntax, there is a ondatabound event in your gridview, but what is the condition to put the radio button enabled or disabled?

Comment: Basically, it's when the user has permissions to change the value of the radio button. so if(currentuser.hasPermission) then set enabled or disabled. Do you think the having 2 dt.Columns (rbType and rbText) and binding them to the itemtemplate radiobutton property is good acceptable code for my requirements? Thanks!

Comment: when user has permission to change, he can change all radio buttons in gridview, rigth?

Comment: not all - there is one more check based on group, he can only change the radiobuttons based on the group he belongs to. so some radiobuttons will be enabled and some will be disabled

Comment: Maybe you can use onrowdatabound event:                                                   protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            
                    RadioButton rb = GridView1.Columns[0] as RadioButton;
                    rb.Enabled = //your value here depends of de user
        }
    }

Comment: You should have a method in backend call grd1_RowDataBound

Comment: Yeah that's what i have sorry for the typo i have method  grd1_RowDataBound. I do my datatable binding on a button click to show the radgrid

Comment: i did a test, i had itemdatabound event in the gridview and this fires on the codebehind with the method i created: grd1_ItemDataBound. but my rowdatabound method isn't firing at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74854/discussion-between-danielvorph-and-shinra-tensei).